# Как скачать файл в selenium если всплывает окно подтверждения

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation

Нужно скачать файл с помощью selenium, но после нажатия кнопки скачать, появляется окно, требующее подтвердить действие (если просто вручную это делать, то предупреждения не будет)

Comment: Какое именно окно? В чём проблема подтвердить?

Comment: Отключить подтверждение при скачивании можно через настройки браузера, которые передаются в конструктор `WebDriver`a, тут зависит уже от конкретного браузера и есть ли такая настройка для него (для хрома/ff точно есть, для остальных надо искать).

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге браузера будут два параметра которые вас могут интересовать:

1. Папка загрузок по умолчанию
2. Спрашивать ли подтверждение при загрузке файла, или скачивать без подтверждения.

Меняете эти параметры в профиле браузера при объявлении, и радуетесь жизни.

**P.S.** Почему в моём ответе нет конкретностей или что ещё лучше, готового кода, потому что в вашем вопросе этого тоже нет. Ни я, ни другие участники SO не экстрасенсы, и никто не знает, что вы там у себя запускаете и самое главное, каким кодом. И в таком случае, ответа господина @hoefling в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017551/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-selenium-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment1732524_1017551) достаточен более чем полностью.

**P.S. 2** Размещая **подробный вопрос со всеми тонкостями**, вы не нам помогаете, а **себе**! Вопрос заданный "от балды" скорее всего будет проигнорирован участниками SO которые, могли бы вам помочь.